# Swift: How to load a Bundle from a static method

Tags: swift

Normally, it's pretty easy to load a `Bundle` for a class from an instance method:

```
class SomeClass
    func foo() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        // ...
    }
}
```

But what if we're in a static method?

```
class SomeClass
    static func foo() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: ???)

    }
}
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff like `SomeClass.type`, etc, but haven't figured it out.

Also, I'm hoping to use one of the other initializers such as URL or identifier since that's fragile.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use ClassName.self.

```
class SomeClass
    static func foo() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: SomeClass.self)

    }
}
```

Comment: Or just `let bundle = Bundle(for: self)`

Comment: Thanks.  Both the accepted answer as well as Martin R's response `let bundle = Bundle(for: self)` work.  Great :)

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5

```
static func foo() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
   }
```